# Why $\int_c^{x+h}f(t) dt-\int_c^x f(t) dt = A(x+h)-A(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I'm reading Apostol's: *Calculus* and trying to understand the fundamental theorem of calculus.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I don't understand why $\int_c^{x+h}f(t) dt-\int_c^x f(t) dt = A(x+h)-A(x)$. I guess the integrals are supposed to be the areas below the curve, but how do they become $A(x+h)-A(x)$? If I were to deduce, I'd say that the are is the sum of the intervals in a step function, not $A(x+h)-A(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definition $$A(x)=\int_c^xf(t)dt.$$ Thus $$A(x+h)=\int_c^{x+h}f(t)dt.$$ Subtracting, $$A(x+h)-A(x)=\int_c^{x+h}f(t)dt-\int_c^xf(t)dt.$$ More concisely - it's just the definition.